# Increment and Decrement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is the increment/decrement step comes after/before the print function

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sum=0
index=0
while sum<10:
    sum+=my_list[index]
    index+=1
    print(sum)
```

Comment: Clearly it is before the `print`. Otherwise you would see `0` as the first output.

Comment: unfortunately i am getting the same answer, plus you can't get 0 as your first element of the list is not zero.

Comment: incrementing the `index` variable should happen after you use it to get the current value from `my_list`. After that it does not influence what is printed (only `sum` is printed not `index`), so it may come before or after the `print` statement.

Comment: it makes sense now, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the `while` is executed from top to bottom. You first tried to increment the value of `sum` by the value of the first index of the `my_list` then you printed the `sum`. If you want to see the `0` as your first output, you have to do the printing first.

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
sum = 0
index = 0
while sum < 10:
    print(sum)
    sum += my_list[index]
    index += 1
```

output:

```
0
1
3
6
```

Also do not use built-in names(here `sum`) as your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. Why? You increment the index for the NEXT run, in the current run you don't need it anymore (you don't need it in the current run after `sum+=my_list[index]`.
Either way, you start with the index 0 and your first sum is 1 (0+1).

Comment: My answer is only regarding to the index increment. Putting sum increment before/behind the print depends on the answer you want to get (see the answer of @SorosH Bakhtiary).